# $A = \{x | f(x) \leq g(x)\}$ is closed in $X$

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to solve a problem in topology. The problem is as follows:

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $Y$ be an ordered set with its order topology. let $f, g : X \rightarrow Y$ be continuous. Show that the set $A = \{x \mid f(x) \leq g(x)\}$ is closed in $X.$

My attempt:

Let $A = \{x  \mid f(x) \leq g(x)\}$. We will prove $X-A = \{x \mid f(x) > g(x) \}$ is open. If $X -A $ is empty, we are done. Suppose that $X-A$ is non-empty and $x_0 \in X-A$. There exist $a,b,c $ elements of $Y$ such that $a < g(x_0) < b <f(x_0) < c$. Now we will show the existence of open sets $U$ and $V$ of $f(x_0)$ and $g(x_0)$ respectively. We will consider the cases:

$\text{Case 1:}$ If $a$ does not exist not exist, i.e., $g(x_0)$ is the minimal element of $Y$, then take $U = (b,c)$ and $V = [g(x_0), b)$. Thus, $U$ and $V$ are open in $Y$.

$\text{Case 2:}$ If $c$ does not exist, i.e., $f(x_0)$ is the maximal element of $Y$, then take $U = (b,f(x_0)]$ and $V = (a,b)$. Thus, $U$ and $V$ are open in $Y$.

$\text{Case 3:}$ If $b$ does not exist, then $U = (g(x_0) ,c)$ and $V = (a, f(x_0))$, thus both are open in $Y$.

By the continuity of $f \ \text{and} \ g$ , we see that $f^{-1} (U)$ and $g^{-1} (V)$ are open in $X$, hence  $f^{-1} (U) \cap g^{-1} (V)$ is an open set  containing $x_0$ and entirely contained in $X-A$. Since $x_0$ is an arbitrary element of $X-A$, we conclude that $X-A$ is open.

Please check my attempt. I don't know my solution is right or wrong. Can I write more clearly the last paragraph of the solution?

Please help me.

Comment: What does “open sets $U$ and $V$ of $f(x_0)$ and $g(x_0)$” mean? That is, what is an open set of a point?

Comment: Yes open sets about $f(x_0)$ and $g(x_0)$.

Comment: Do you mean open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $f(x_0)\in U$ and that $g(x_0)\in V$?

Comment: I want to mean $U,V$ are neighborhoods about $f(x_0)$ and $g(x_0)$.

Comment: You have considered whether a single one of $a,b,c$ don't exist. What if two of them don't exist? What if none of them exist? And what about the case where they all exist? It seems like you skipped that one.

Comment: @Arthur Are you saying  about the case that if $g(x)$ is the smallest element and $f(x)$ is the largest element and there is no $b\in Y$ such that $g(x) < b < f(x)$? If then should I take $U = (g(x), f(x)]$ and $V = [g(x), f(x))?

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is fine, but that proof can be improved.

First, a matter of notation. It's usually better to write $X\setminus A$ rather than $X-A$. The later options is sometimes ambiguous.

And you can forget about $a$ and $c$. If there is a $b$ such that $g(x_0)<b<f(x_0)$, you can take$$U=\{y\in Y\mid b<y\}\quad\text{and}\quad V=\{y\in Y\mid y<b\};$$otherwise, you can take$$U=\{y\in Y\mid y<g(x_0)\}\quad\text{and}\quad V=\{y\in Y\mid f(x_0)<y\}.$$In both cases, $U$ is a neighborhood of $f(x_0)$ and $V$ is a neighborhood of $g(x_0)$. So, $f^{-1}(U)\cap g^{-1}(V)$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$ and it is a subset of $X\setminus A$. So, $X\setminus A$ is a neighborhood of all of its points, and therefore it is an open set.

Comment: When no algebraic operation on $X$ is ever mentioned, I think it's fine to use $X-A$. But in general, yeah, $X\setminus A$ is safer.

Comment: @Arthur Not that I wrote that $X-A$ is *sometimes* ambiguous.

Comment: You also said unconditionally that $X\setminus A$ is better. I sometimes prefer to use $X-A$.

Comment: @Arthur Right. I've added the word “usually” to my answer.

Comment: What would be a situation where $X-A$ leads to a problem? The sign $\setminus$ or $/$ is completly overused in mathematics, and I prefer to write $-$ for set difference.

Comment: No, you cannot. Suppose that $b=f(x_0)=c$. In general, $[b,c](=\{c\})$ will *not* be an open set.

Comment: @Cornman If $A,B\subset\Bbb C$, what is $A-B$? Is it $\{a\in A\mid a\notin B\}$ or is it $\{a-b\mid a\in A\wedge b\in B\}$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think $a \leq g(x_0) < b < f(x_0) \leq c$ will work and cover all the cases. And the case in your answer $g(x_0) < b < f(x_0) $ is also included in $a \leq g(x_0) < b <f(x_0) \leq c$. Am I right?

Comment: But then why would $(b,c]$ be a neighborhood of $f(x_0)$?

Comment: $(b,c]$ is open in $Y$. Clearly, $f(x_0) \in (b,c]$. Munkres tells in his book that "$U$ is a nbd of $x$" equivalent to "$U$ is an open set containing $x$".

Comment: If $c=f(x_0)$, why would $(b,c]$ be a neighborhood of $f(x_0)$?

Comment: I think if $c = f(x_0)$, then $f(x_0)$ is the largest element. and $(b,c]$ is open in $Y$ and $f(x_0) \in (b,c]$. I might be wrong. Please correct me.

Comment: Yes, in that case $f(x_0)$ will be the larges element of $(b,c]$. But it doesn't have to be the largest element of $Y$. And then there is no reason for $(b,c]$ to be an open set.

Comment: @Cornan $/$ is very overused. $\setminus$ is rather uncommon outside of set difference.