# Proving $\{x | f (x) \le g(x)\}$ is closed in $X$

Tags: general-topology

The problem which this question concerns has been asked [many](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165432/let-y-be-an-ordered-set-in-the-order-topology-with-f-gx-rightarrow-y-contin) [times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3871150/prove-that-x-in-x-fx-leq-gx-is-a-closed-set) [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4189205/a-x-fx-leq-gx-is-closed-in-x), but I want to get some clarification about a particular point about the proof.

The problem is from Munkres,

> Let $Y$ be a simply ordered set in the order topology. Let $f, g: X \mapsto Y$ be continuous functions. Show that $\{x | f (x) \le g (x)\}$ is closed in $X$.

Letting $A = \{x | f (x) \le g (x)\}$, it seems simpler to show that the complement $X - A$ is open. To do so, we can show that for any $x_0 \in X - A$, there exists $U_0$ open in $X$ such that $x_0 \in U_0 \subseteq A$. Starting with $x_0 \in X - A \implies f (x_0) > g(x_0)$, and noting that the order topology is Hausdorff, $f (x_0) \ne g (x_0)$ implies the existence of disjoint neighborhoods $V_0, W_0$ of $f (x_0)$, $g (x_0)$, respectively.

Other solutions seem to imply that taking $U_0 = f^{-1} (V_0) \cap g^{-1} (W_0)$ completes the proof, but here is where I am stuck. It's easy to see that $U_0$ is open, since it is the intersection of two open sets: $f^{-1} (V_0)$ and $g^{-1} (W_0)$ are open by hypothesis that $f, g$ are continuous. It's equally easy to see that $x_0 \in U_0$, since $f (x_0) \in V_0 \implies x_0 \in f^{-1} (V_0)$ and $g (x_0) \in W_0 \implies x_0 \in g^{-1} (W_0)$. But how does one show that $U_0 \subseteq X - A$? To me, it seems that inclusion in the preimage sets of neighborhoods of the image $f (x_0)$ and $g (x_0)$ is not sufficient to imply inclusion in $X - A$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $Y$ be an ordered set in the order topology with $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ continuous, show that $\{x:f(x)\leq g(x)\}$ is closed in $X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165432/let-y-be-an-ordered-set-in-the-order-topology-with-f-gx-rightarrow-y-contin)

Comment: @HeroZhang001 Not really. The top answer there, which is along the lines of what I am thinking, doesn't make a lot of sense. It is the range topology that is Hausdorff, not the domain.

Comment: In the answer linked in the comments, $V_0, W_0$ are not any disjoint open sets, they also have the property that everything in $V_0$ is bigger than things in $W_0$. Such open sets can be chosen due to the ordering in $Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your construction of $V_0$ and $W_0$ you cannot guarantee that $U_0\subseteq X-A$. And in fact, with such arbitrary choice it is not even true in general.

Those sets have to be chosen more carefuly. More precisely, we consider two cases:

1. There is $z$ such that $f(x_0)>z>g(x_0)$. Then we choose $V_0=\{y\in Y\ |\ y>z\}$ and $W_0=\{y\in Y\ |\ z>y\}$.
2. There is no $z$ between $f(x_0)$ and $g(x_0)$. Then we choose $V_0=\{y\in Y\ |\ y>g(x_0)\}$ and $W_0=\{y\in Y\ |\ f(x_0)> y\}$. Note that these are still disjoint because there is no $z$ between $f(x_0)$ and $g(x_0)$.

This implies that $V_0>W_0$ (meaning every element of $V_0$ is bigger than every element of $W_0$) and so $U_0\subseteq X-A$, as expected.

Comment: I see. So the Hausdorff / T2 condition (existence of disjoint neighborhoods of unequal points) is not, by itself, sufficient to give the desired $V_0, W_0$, correct? They have to be disjoint *and* satisfy the condition that each element of $V_0$ is strictly larger than each element of $W_0$, which is provided by the open rays $(z, \infty)$ and $(-\infty, z)$ (or $(g(x_0), \infty)$ and $(-\infty, f(x_0))$, in the case that $f(x_0)$ is the immediate successor of $g(x_0)$).

Comment: @K.Jiang yes, correct.